# Do I need a visa for Georgia?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, georgia-country, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian, holding a valid schengen visa issued by the French embassy, and a multiple entry visa for the United States. Will I be allowed to enter Tbilisi in Georgia?

Answer (score 5):

According to https://matsne.gov.ge/en/document/view/2867377:

> List of Countries, Whose Visa and/or Residence Permit Holders May Enter Georgia without a Visa for an Appropriate Period and under Appropriate Conditions
>
> ...
>
> United States of America
>
> ...
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. Aliens holding a visa and/or a residence permit of any country listed in the annex may enter and stay in Georgia without visa for 90 calendar days in any 180-day period.
> 2. For the purpose of entering and staying in Georgia without visa, a visa and/or a residence permit of a respective country shall be valid on the day of entry into Georgia (crossing the border), which must be evidenced by a travel and/or other appropriate document.

You can also fill out a few details about yourself (intent of travel, citizenship, ...) at https://geoconsul.gov.ge/en/visaInformation and it will tell you whether you need a visa.

In general, you should be good to go, assuming your US-visa is still valid.

Answer (score 3):

As a Nigerian citizen, you will typically need a visa to enter Tbilisi, Georgia. Nigeria is not on the list of countries whose citizens can enter Georgia visa free. The complete list can be found [here](http://agenda.ge/news/36828/eng)

However bearers of **valid French visas** or **valid USA visas can enter Georgia** without a visa per the [Legislative Herald of Georgia](https://matsne.gov.ge/en/document/view/2867377).

You can also find a simplified map for visa requirements to enter Georgia on [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Georgia#/media/File:Visa_policy_of_Georgia.png).

> Holders of visas or residence permits of EU/EFTA/GCC countries,
>   overseas territories of EU countries (except Anguilla, Montserrat,
>   Pitcairn, Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha), Australia,
>   Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, South Korea or the United States
>   do not require a visa for max 90 days in a 180-day period. The
>   visa/residence permit must be valid on arrival to Georgia.

Comment: OP didn't say anthing about a UK visa. Also, I'm not sure whether your information is up-to-date.

Comment: @martin.koeberl Thanks for the pointer. Noted and updated.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ng&DE=tbs&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a valid visa issued
>   by an **EEA Member State**, Australia, Bahrain,
>   Bermuda, Canada, Cayman Isl., Falkland Isl. (Malvinas),
>   Gibraltar, Israel, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait, New Zealand,
>   Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Switzerland, Turks and Caicos Isl.,
>   **USA**, United Arab Emirates or Virgin Isl. (British) **for a
>   maximum stay of 90 days**.

So yes, you can enter Georgia on the basis of your French or US visa.