# What are the Georgia entry rules for an Indian national with a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, georgia-country, vacations

I want to vacation in the country of Georgia. I have an Indian passport, and have a Schengen visa. Can I enter Georgia with this Schengen visa, or do I need to get another visa?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Legislative Herald of Georgia](https://matsne.gov.ge/en/document/view/2867377):

> List of Countries, Whose Visa and/or Residence Permit Holders May Enter Georgia without a Visa for an Appropriate Period and under Appropriate Conditions
>
> [...]
>
> Republic of Austria
>
> Kindgom of Belgium
>
> [...]
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. Aliens holding a visa and/or a residence permit of any country listed in the annex may enter and stay in Georgia without visa for 90 calendar days in any 180-day period.
> 2. For the purpose of entering and staying in Georgia without visa, a visa and/or a residence permit of a respective country shall be valid on the day of entry into Georgia (crossing the border), which must be evidenced by a travel and/or other appropriate document.

(Note that you can also find all other Schengen members on this list, I just copied the first two.)

You can also fill out a few details about yourself (intent of travel, citizenship, ...) at [the Georgian visa information page](https://geoconsul.gov.ge/en/visaInformation) and it will tell you whether you need a visa.

In general, you should be good to go, assuming your Schengen visa is still valid.

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&DE=ge&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, gives the same information:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a visa issued by an
>   EEA Member State [...] for a maximum stay of 90 days.

[Note, I copied parts of my answer at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89388/54794 for this answer, I hope this is allowed.]